# PySide2 and supporting addToJavaScriptWindowObject

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyside2, qwebengineview, qtwebchannel

I am trying to port PySide application version #1 to PySide2 and struggle to find the solution for porting following code snippet:

```
class AppManager(QtCore.QObject):
    '''
    methods of AppObject will be available from javascript
    '''
    def __init__(self, webview):
        QtCore.QObject.__init__(self)


class WebView(QWebEngineView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QWebEngineView.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setPage(WebEnginePage(self))

    def contextMenuEvent(self, event):
        pass


class AppWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.view = WebView(self)
        self.page = self.view.page()
        self.app_manager = AppManager(self.view)
        self.page.mainFrame().addToJavaScriptWindowObject('app_manager', self.app_manager)
        # ERROR in above line !!!
```

I can't find in documentation where I have to find possible fix

Comment: [QWebChannel](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebchannel.html)

Answer (score 5):

You have to use QWebChannel, for that you have to download [qwebchannel.js](https://github.com/qt/qtwebchannel/blob/5.12/examples/webchannel/shared/qwebchannel.js) (link leads to **qwebchannel.js** for Qt **5.12**, for different versions change github branch).

In the following code I show an example:

```
.
├── index.html
├── main.py
└── qwebchannel.js
```

**main.py**

```
import sys

from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets, QtWebChannel


class WebEnginePage(QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEnginePage):
    pass

class AppManager(QtCore.QObject):
    textChanged = QtCore.Signal(str)
    def __init__(self, webview):
        QtCore.QObject.__init__(self)
        self.m_text = ""

        timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)
        timer.timeout.connect(self.on_timeout)
        timer.start(1000)

    def on_timeout(self):
        self.text  = QtCore.QDateTime.currentDateTime().toString()

    @QtCore.Property(str, notify=textChanged)
    def text(self):
        return self.m_text

    @text.setter
    def setText(self, text):
        if self.m_text == text:
            return
        self.m_text = text
        self.textChanged.emit(self.m_text)


class WebView(QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setPage(WebEnginePage(self))

    def contextMenuEvent(self, event):
        pass


class AppWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.view = WebView(self)
        self.page = self.view.page()
        self.app_manager = AppManager(self.view)
        channel = QtWebChannel.QWebChannel(self)
        self.page.setWebChannel(channel)
        channel.registerObject("app_manager", self.app_manager)
        self.view.load(QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile(QtCore.QDir.current().filePath("index.html")))
        self.setCentralWidget(self.view)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = AppWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./qwebchannel.js"></script>
</head>
<header><title>This is title</title></header>
<body>

<p id="output"></p>

<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
        new QWebChannel(qt.webChannelTransport, function (channel) {
            window.app_manager = channel.objects.app_manager;
            console.log(app_manager);

            app_manager.textChanged.connect(function(message) {
                document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "Received message: " + message;
            });

        });
    }
</script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In this case using the proposed qwebchannel.js -file will be free for software creators based? Or should they order paid version of PyQT?

Comment: @YoungMaster it is part of Qt: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.9/qtwebengine-webenginewidgets-markdowneditor-resources-qwebchannel-js.html, 
the license is in the file so I recommend reading it.